# Returning PHP variables data back to an HTML Page

Tags: php, html

I am fairly new to php and have only written basic post email returns. However what im trying to achive now is to return the data held within a variable back to the webpage in a specific location on the page.

So far I have a form that collects the data Name & Surname, this is collected by php.

```
$firstnameField = $_POST ['name'];
$surnameField = $_POST ['surname'];
```

All I want to do is print the data within these variables back to the screen in a specific location on the page. I have looked around but others are talking about databases and ajax, and I havent the slightest about that stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are thousands of examples of this at php.net - did you try looking there? For posterity: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: try to store these values in  `session` and retrieve `$_SESSION['name']` where you want

Comment: I did'nt know this page existed ill check it out. :)

Comment: how did you posted the name,surname? via form? javascript? Ajax & Jquery is a must in dynamic html manipulation, learn them.

Comment: I see PHP.net is a usefull link however i need the code to run server side rather than client side. is there a way to do this in a php script file ?

Comment: PHP is an server side language, so it always run server side. I think you need to start reading about php first.

Comment: @mjayt does not matter, search PHP on wikipedia and the first line is `PHP is a server-side scripting language designed for web development`. A action that takes 10 seconds...

Comment: Your comment didn't improve the thread... but it isn't that important to me so let's move on.

Comment: Google the word infer... then, maybe INFER from his question that he was looking for a PHP only solution... Jeez, his question actually implies that he KNOWS it is a server side language, as in "Can't I do this server side? Is there a way to do this in a PHP script file". That again implies that he knows PHP is server side. You're not even getting my point, but by all means, continue to beat the dead horse a little more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple: just use echo/print inside a `<?php ?>` code block wherever you want that variable printed in your document:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $firstname = $_POST['name'];
}

?>

<html>

<body>

<?php if (isset($firstname)) { echo "<p>Hello, $firstname</p>"; } ?>

<form method="POST">
Enter a name: <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this looks perfect ill implement it and give it a try! :)

Comment: I cant seem to get this working its just returing the actual php code

Comment: if you see php code in your browser, then your server's misconfigured. and of course, this script has to be served up a webserver. your browser cannot run php directly.

Comment: Ahh I got it! :) All working now. I'm a very happy bunny! thanks for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["dataEntered"])) && ($_POST["dataEntered"] == "Yes"))
echo "Hello! " . $_POST["name"] . " " . $_POST["surname"];
else
{
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" size="32" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Surname:</td>
            <td><input name="surname" type="text" id="surname" value="" size="32" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Send Form" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="dataEntered" value="Yes" />
      </form>
 <?php
}
?>
```